# How to Additional attribute to object

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Im new to Django and Python which I'm using to create a Hotel Booking website.

Im trying to fetch all the rooms associated with a hotel 
With the returned object Im trying to add an extra attribute onto each room returned.
This attribute will equal a variable .

Example:

```
rooms = Room.object.filter(hotel=thehotel)
// for each room in rooms
Roomsavailable = Room.totalrooms
Roomsleft = RoomsAvailable - RoomsBooked

//attach roomsleft onto each room object
room.spaceleft = Roomsleft
```

Any help would be appreciated , hope i've explained it ok.

Comment: You want to add the number of free rooms in the hotel as a property of the *rooms*? Surely that's a property of the *hotel*?

Comment: Its calculated depending on the number of Reservations .

Comment: Yes, I get that. My point is that the number of free rooms doesn't really belong to *a room*, it belongs to *the whole hotel*.

Comment: Hey thanks for commenting , I actually figured it out after looking at the code in the question a couple of times. All i wanted to do was attach the space left attribute onto each of the objects retrieved from the database and pass this attribute to the view.

Comment: Then please either write an answer or delete the question - don't put answers *in* the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed to have found my own answer by staring at the question post code.

**Anyways for people that may stumble upon this:**

```
rooms = Room.objects.filter(hotel= thehotel) *// thehotel refers to an ID*

for room in rooms:
      room.spaceleft = 0   //setting the additional attribute
context = {'rooms':rooms}

*//passing the context to the template.*

return render(request, 'HotelApp/hoteldetails.html', context)
```

**Then in the Template :**

```
{% for room in rooms %}

<p> Rooms Left: {{room.spaceleft}} </p>   // using the additional attribute
{% endfor %}
```